# How to implement generics with type annotations in F#

Tags: generics, f#

I have the following skeleton of code:

```
type MyException<'T> () =
    inherit Exception()

type IMyInterface =
    abstract member Method<'T when 'T : (new: unit -> 'T) and 'T :> Exception> : string -> int

type MyClass =
    interface IMyInterface with
        member this.Method s =
            let i = s.IndexOf "a"
            if i = -1 then raise (new MyException<'T> ())
            i
```

However, I am getting the following message:

> This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'T has been constrained to be type 'obj'.

and when compiled, `obj` is passed to MyException instead of `'T`.

I need to have the above type constraints on `IMyInterface.Method`, and also need to pass the type passed into `MyException` in `MyClass.Method`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to parametrise `MyClass`:

```
type MyClass<'T> =
    interface IMyInterface with
        member this.Method s =
            let i = s.IndexOf "a"
            if i = -1 then raise (new MyException<'T> ())
            i
```

or repeat constraints on your method:

```
type MyClass =
    interface IMyInterface with
        member this.Method<'T when 'T : (new: unit -> 'T) and 'T :> Exception> s =
            let i = s.IndexOf "a"
            if i = -1 then raise (new MyException<'T> ())
            i
```